# View vl_slic output matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, vlfeat

I feel like this is a fairly simple question but I can't seem to figure it out. I'm trying to use VLFEAT's `vl_slic` function in MATLAB and I'm using the documentation used at this page: http://www.vlfeat.org/overview/slic.html

What I'm having trouble figuring out is how to display and image with the corresponding segments overlaid. What I currently have is this:

```
img = imread('slic_image.jpg');
regionSize = 30 ;
regularizer = 1  ;
vl_setup
segments = vl_slic(single(img), regionSize, regularizer);
imshow(img);hold on;
imshow(segments);
```

But all I see is a black image. I'm not sure how to get my output to look more like the output on the webpage above.

Answer (score 1):

I have currently no access to MatLab - so no chance to actually try it - but have a look at the following function. According to the source code of VLFeat, the function `vl_slic` returns the labels as matrix:

```
% VL_SLIC  SLIC superpixels
%   SEGMENTS = VL_SLIC(IM, REGIONSIZE, REGULARIZER) extracts the SLIC
%   superpixes [1] from image IM. REGIONSIZE is the starting size of
%   the superpixels and REGULARIZER is the trades-off appearance for
%   spatial regularity when clustering (a larger value results in more
%   spatial regularization). SEGMENTS is a UINT32 array containing the
%   superpixel identifier for each image pixel.
```

The function `draw_contours` is defined as follows:

```
function [contourImg] = draw_contours(labels, img)
% function [contourImg] = draw_contours(labels, img)
%
% David Stutz <david.stutz@rwth-aachen.de>

    rows = size(img, 1);
    cols = size(img, 2);

    contourImg = img;
    for i = 1: rows
        for j = 1: cols
            label = labels(i, j);
            labelTop = 0;
            labelBottom = 0;
            labelLeft = 0;
            labelRight = 0;

            if i > 1
                labelTop = labels(i - 1, j);
            end;
            if j > 1
                labelLeft = labels(i, j - 1);
            end;
            if i < rows
                labelBottom = labels(i + 1, j);
            end;
            if j < cols
                labelRight = labels(i, j + 1);
            end;

            if labelTop ~= 0 && labelTop ~= label
                contourImg(i, j, 1) = 0;
                contourImg(i, j, 2) = 0;
                contourImg(i, j, 3) = 0;
            end;
            if labelLeft ~= 0 && labelLeft ~= label
                contourImg(i, j, 1) = 0;
                contourImg(i, j, 2) = 0;
                contourImg(i, j, 3) = 0;
            end;
            if labelBottom ~= 0 && labelBottom ~= label
                contourImg(i, j, 1) = 0;
                contourImg(i, j, 2) = 0;
                contourImg(i, j, 3) = 0;
            end;
            if labelRight ~= 0 && labelRight ~= label
                contourImg(i, j, 1) = 0;
                contourImg(i, j, 2) = 0;
                contourImg(i, j, 3) = 0;
            end;
        end;
    end;
end
```

Given an image `img = imread('path/to/image');`, simply extract the superpixels and then draw a contour image:

```
img = imread('path/to/image');
labels = vl_slic(img, regionSize, regularizer);
contourImg = draw_contours(labels, img);
imshow(contourImg);
```

The function `draw_contours` has been tested using Turbopixels superpixels [2]. The below image shows the result of VLFeat's implementaiton of SLIC [3] using a comparable function for drawing contours implemented in C++, and the superpixels extracted using the C interface of VLFeat. The C++ source code can be found on GitHub: https://github.com/davidstutz/vlfeat-slic-example

[image: SLIC superpixels extracted using VLFeat's implementation with regularization set to 1000 and region size set to 20.]

- [2] A. Levinshtein, A. Stere, K. N. Kutulakos, D. J. Fleet, S. J. Dickinson, K. Siddiqi. Turbopixels: Fast Superpixels Using Geometric Flows. IEEE Transactions on Pattern Analysis and Machine Intelligence, pages 2290 – 2297, 2009.
- [3] R. Achanta, A. Shaji, K. Smith, A. Lucchi, P. Fua, S. Susstrunk. SLIC Superpixels. Technical report, EPFL, Lausanne, 2010.

Comment: This code actually draws contours. The single problem is that if I give it a grayscale image it returns an 3-channel image with red all over. Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: This is because the function expects a color image to be given and, therefore, treats your grayscale image as the R-channel of the created color image. To fix this you can simply convert your grayscale image to a three-channel grayscale image, for example using `cat(3, grayImage, grayImage, grayImage)`.